# Laravel 8 Min Price

Tags: laravel-8

I have more than on price for one product
with **MIN** i can get the lowest price

```
dd($minPriceDealer=ScrapingPrices::where('product_id',$mobile->pro_id)->min('price'));
```

this show lowest price only ... how i can get all row data

```
dd($minPriceDealer=ScrapingPrices::where('product_id',$mobile->pro_id)->min('price')->select(['price','id']));
```

> error: Call to a member function select() on int

Comment: i try to do this 
$minPriceDealer=ScrapingPrices::where('product_id',$mobile->pro_id)->select(['price','id'])->min('price');

but same problem get price only

Answer (score 0):

i find solution

```
$minPriceDealer=ScrapingPrices::where('product_id',$mobile->pro_id)
        ->select('id','title','price', DB::raw('MIN(price) as cheapest_price'))
        ->groupBy('id')
        ->first();
```